# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Site__c.Home_Content_Body__c

Tags: visualforce

Site extenion class:

```
public with sharing class siteExtension {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    private Set<String> SiteFields = new Set<String>();

    public siteExtension (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fields = 
        Schema.SobjectType.Site__c.fields.getMap();

        for (String s : fields.keySet()) {
        // Only include accessible fields 
            if (fields.get(s).getDescribe().isAccessible() && 
                fields.get(s).getDescribe().isCustom()) {
                    SiteFields.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public  List<String> availableFields {
        get {
            controller.reset(); 
            controller.addFields(new List<String>(SiteFields));
                return new List<String>(SiteFields);
        }
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="{!Site__c.Name}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!availableFields}" var="field">
        <h2><apex:outputText 
             value="{!$ObjectType['Site__c'].Fields[field].Label}"/></h2>
        <br/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!Site__c[field]}" /><br/><br/>

    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Why do I get this error:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Site__c.Home_Content_Body__c

I followed the tutorial from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_sample_custom.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard controller by default will query for all fields referenced directly on the page. However, if you reference them dynamically instead, you need to explicitly add them *in your constructor*. Note that this operation cannot be performed in a test.

I would reorganize your code slightly as well:

```
public List<String> availableFields { get; private set; }
public siteExtension (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    availableFields = new List<String>();
    // populate via existing logic
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(availableFields);
}
```

Comment: Just an extra note that the `!Test.isRunningTest()` is because you cannot call `addFields` when you created the `ApexPages.StandardController` yourself. If you plan to re-use this controller internally at all you will need to instead overload the constructor or come up with a similar pattern where you know that you are constructing it yourself as opposed to the Visualforce engine constructing it.